# How to deploy Laravel/Lumen Framework to the production server

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, lumen

I created a project using vue.js for the frontend and backend with laravel lumen framework and my question is how can I deploy my backend laravel/lumen to the production server ?

is there any specific commands ? by the way my production server setup 
running with Digitalocean Ubuntu droplet and I used Nginx as a web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, i think we can have any of 3 solutions: 
**Solution 1**
     If you own a domain; set a subdomain for backend as `api.yourdomain.com` and access it through your frontend. 
**Solution 2**
     Configure your web server (apache/nginx/{whatever-you-use}) to listen on 80 for frontend request and listen on 81 or anyother port and use that url "yourdomain.com:81" for backend and access it through frontend.
**Solution 3**
     Define a specific route for apis like "yourdomain.com/api" on your web server to use that location to point your backend lumen server and regular location / for frontend.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know Vue.js files are part of that framework so whole project will be deployed

Comment: separate front-end project and separate back-end project , I created dist version of vue.js front-end framework and that that collaborate with back-end lumen